# In Kaggle while installing paramiko getting connectionErrors

Tags: paramiko, kaggle

Getting below warning and errors.

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7e8ff10a7850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/paramiko/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7e8ff10a7b80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/paramiko/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7e8ff10a7e20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/paramiko/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7e8ff10a7fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/paramiko/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7e8ff0ecc1c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/paramiko/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement paramiko (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for paramiko

I tired restarting kernel, restarting system but bothing works

Is there is any other alternative or how to install it . I tired pip install paramiko and pip install paramiko-2.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.

Answer (score 0):

click on your photo profile , go to settings and verify your acount with phone verification.Finally, in your notebook go to "Notebook options" and activate the internet option. And there you go.
ps:I just found this solution, and it works for me.
[you can check it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJcXr.png)